# Check if a field value exists in a JSONB array inside another table's field

Tags: database, postgresql, jsonb

For simplicity, let's assume that I have two tables: `A` and `B`.

Table A has a JSONB field called `data` with the field `columns`.
This JSONB array is just a list of ids that are primary keys in Table B.

Table B has the field `id` (the others don't matter for the question).

The idea is to create a constraint so that it's impossible to delete a row in Table B if this row's `id` is IN `A.data->'columns'`.

As far as I know, it's impossible to create such constrains in a conventional way so I have decided that this behavior can be implemented as:

```
SELECT *
FROM B
WHERE id = ANY (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY(
    SELECT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(A.data -> 'cols') FROM A)::int[]
                           )
);
```

This query supposedly does exactly what I want, but it looks clumsy enough to assume that there must be a fancier way. Constructing an array and then unnesting it doesn't seem to be optimal anyway.

Can you think of a better way to achieve the behavior I described above?

Comment: Normalize your data model, then you can define proper foreign keys. Everything else will be an ugly hack.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, 
That would help, but the JSONB field I mention above is essentially an SQL statement divided into blocks as a JSON object. For example, it can have keys like `select_fields`, `join_tables`, `join_conditions` where values are arrays. Denormalizing that would create a beast of a table